# Get url as www.abcd.com?curr=USD

Tags: php, url, get, currency

I am working on e-commerce website
I have a drop down of different currencies if user selects `USD` as currency then all the links in the website should open as `www.abcd.com/aboutus.php?curr=USD`

Thanks

Comment: Its not a good idea to post please help. Show that you have googled research and attempted! This was an easy solution but for future reference this is not how it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form action='www.abcd.com/aboutus.php' method='get'>
 <select name="curr" id='test'>
 <option value='USD'>USD</option>
 <option value='Euro'>Euro</option>
 </select>
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
 </form>
```

on your pages simply put

```
 <? $curr = $_GET['curr'];  ?>
```

now on every link include

```
 abcd.com?curr=<? echo $curr ?>
```

Comment: +1 for typing in text box :) lol so use to having my editor suggest

Comment: i want the all links in website should be opened as www.abcd.com/anypage.php?curr=USD

Comment: what page are the links located on ? aboutus.php

Comment: of every page on site to inclue?curr=USD

Comment: every page has links eg: products.php, careers.php, newoffers.php etc.. so if he selects a currency from drop down what ever link he click should be opened as defined in above comment

Comment: Does this make sense ?

Comment: let me know! if it works dont forget to mark the answer with a check! :)

Comment: top left where my answer is you should see a check mark click on it turns it green

Comment: near where the arrow up and down are left side!